# RenderScript GPU performance not on par with device GFLOPS?

Tags: performance, opencl, gpu, benchmarking, renderscript

As a test, I am trying to crunch as much GFLOPS from the GPU as possible, just to see how far we can go with compute via RenderScript.

For this I use a GPU-cache-friendly kernel that will (hopefully) not be bounded on memory access for testing purposes:

```
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed
rs_allocation input;

float __attribute__((kernel)) compute(float in, int x)
{
    float sum = 0;
    if (x < 64) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        sum += rsGetElementAt_float(input, x - i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

On the Java side I just call the kernel a couple of times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    m_script.forEach_compute(m_inAllocation, m_outAllocation);
}
```

With allocation sizes of 1M floats this maxes around 1-2 GFLOPS on a GPU that should max around 100 GFLOPS (Snapdragon 600, APQ8064AB), **that is 50x - 100x less compute performance !**.

I have tried unrolling the loop (10% difference), using larger or smaller sums (<5% diff), different allocation sizes (<5% diff), 1D or 2D allocations (no diff), but come nowhere near the amount of GFLOPS that should be possible on the device. I even am thinking that the entire kernel is only running on the CPUs.

In similar sense, looking at the results of an RenderScript benchmark application [(https://compubench.com/result.jsp?benchmark=compu20](https://compubench.com/result.jsp?benchmark=compu20), the top of the line devices only achieve around 60M pixels/s on a Gaussian blur. A 5x5 blur in naive (non-seperable) implementation takes around 50 FLOPS/pixel, resulting in 3 GFLOPS as opposed to the 300 GFLOPS these GPUs have.

Any thoughts?

(see e.g. http://kyokojap.myweb.hinet.net/gpu_gflops/ for an overview of device capabilities)

EDIT:

Using the OpenCL libs that are available on the device (Samsung S4, 4.4.2) I have rewritten the RenderScript test program to OpenCL and run it via the NDK. With basically the same setup (1M float buffers and running the kernel 1024 times) I can now get around 25 GFLOPS, **that is 10x the RenderScript performance**, and 4x from the theoretical device maximum.

For RenderScript there is no way of knowing if a kernel is running on the GPU. So:

- if the RenderScript kernel does run on the GPU, why is it so slow?
- if the kernel is not running on the GPU, which devices do run RenderScript on the GPU (aside from most probably the Nexus line)?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a much harder math to test the GFLOPS performance. A simple sum is clearly bottlenecking in the memory side (and does not matter how the cache is working, is still bottlenecking). For 100GFLOPS you would need with that kernel 800GB/s memory bandwidth.

Comment: See comments below, this is the kernel used: `float __attribute__((kernel)) saturation(float in, int x, int y)
{
    float sum = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        sum *= in;
    }
    return sum;
}`
This seems to be compute bound

Comment: If your compiler is clever enough, that code will simplify to 'sum*in*64;' Not very compute bound. Try without optimizations.

Comment: This kernel computes `pow(in, 64)`, not `sum*64*in`.

Comment: True, my fault. Anyway, lets hope the compiler is not clever enough to produce optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

What device are you using? Not all devices are shipping with GPU drivers yet.

Also, that kernel will be memory bound, since you've got a 1:1 arithmetic to load ratio.

Comment: I have checked if the GPU caches are not working as expected, in which case the kernel will be memory bound as you suggested, by only using the passed input variable, i.e. sum += in (as opposed to sum += rsGetElementAt_float(input, x - i)). This makes less 10% difference, so the cache works, **the kernel is not memory bound**. Memory computation of GetElement is good btw!

Comment: V/RenderScript_jni﹕ RS native mode
V/RenderScript﹕ 0x75aa80b8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
10-13 23:37:53.649  10893-I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: _msm8960_kk_2.7__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.01
    Build Date: 11/07/13 Thu
    Local Branch: klp
    Remote Branch: quic/hammerhead_klp
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: FWIW: allocation in Java:         `Type type = new Type.Builder(m_rs, Element.F32(m_rs)).setX(1024).setY(1024).create();
        m_inAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(m_rs, type, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);`